# NullPointerException in stack implementation of ArrayDeque

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stack

Hey folks im writing a program to convert infix expressions to postfix ones using stacks, where input is read in from the user. The problem is cases where the stack is empty I keep getting nullpointer exceptions on a section of code that calls peek(). The confounding thing is that I have an if statement that should protect this from occuring using a call to isEmpty(). Any ideas? Specifically, the input "A+B-C" is what is giving me problems, though "(A+B-C)" works perfectly

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Adam
 */
public class PostfixConversion
{
    static Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public static boolean precedence(char first, char second)
    {
        if(first == '+' || first == '-')
            return false;
        else if(first == '*' || first == '/')
        {
            if(second == '*' || second == '/')
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static String convertToPostfix(String infixExp)
    {
        int leftCount = 0;
        int rightCount = 0;
        Character item;

        String rightError = "There is no matching left parenthesis.";
        String leftError = "There is no matching right parenthesis.";
        String postFix = "";

        if(infixExp.indexOf(")") < infixExp.indexOf("("))
            return rightError;
        if(infixExp.lastIndexOf(")") < infixExp.lastIndexOf("("))
            return leftError;

        for(int i = 0; i < infixExp.length(); i++)
        {
            if(Character.isLetter(infixExp.charAt(i)))
                postFix += infixExp.charAt(i);

            if(infixExp.charAt(i) == '(')
            {
                item = infixExp.charAt(i);
                stack.push(item);
                leftCount++;
            }

            if(infixExp.charAt(i) == ')')
            {
                while(stack.peek() != '(')
                    postFix += stack.pop().charValue();
                stack.pop();
                rightCount++;
            }

            if(infixExp.charAt(i) == '+' ||
                infixExp.charAt(i) == '-' ||
                 infixExp.charAt(i) == '*' ||
                  infixExp.charAt(i) == '/')
            {
                if(stack.isEmpty() == false)
                {
                    while(PostfixConversion.precedence(infixExp.charAt(i), stack.peek().charValue()) == false)
                    {
                        if(stack.peek().charValue() == '(')
                            break;
                        postFix += stack.pop().charValue();
                    }
                }

                item = infixExp.charAt(i);
                stack.push(item);
            }
        }

        if(leftCount > rightCount)
            return leftError;
        if(rightCount > leftCount)
            return rightError;

        return postFix;
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the error occurs in the conversion method where the precedence method is called to compare operators (+, - , *, /), the condition of the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following loop:

```
        while(stack.peek() != '(')
            postFix += stack.pop().charValue();
```

you don't check whether the stack has gone empty.

The same goes for the following loop:

```
            while(PostfixConversion.precedence(infixExp.charAt(i), stack.peek().charValue()) == false)
            {
                if(stack.peek().charValue() == '(')
                    break;
                postFix += stack.pop().charValue();
            }
```

Once the stack has gone empty, `peek()` will return `null` and you'll get an NPE from the autounboxing.

Note that the `if` you have around the second `while` is only checked *before* the loop is entered. It's not checked on any subsequent iterations, so won't prevent the scenario I've described above.

Comment: Well, I get the error with the input "A+B-C", so that particular while loop you're pointing out shouldn't be reached right? As for the second one:

Comment: `if(stack.isEmpty() == false)
            {
                while(PostfixConversion.precedence(infixExp.charAt(i), stack.peek().charValue()) == false)
                {
                    if(stack.peek().charValue() == '(')
                        break;
                    postFix += stack.pop().charValue();
                }
            }`

Comment: @AdamChmurzynski: The `if` is *before* the loop. It's not checked again after the first iteration.

Comment: The first iteration of what, I lost ya